# Accessing a kubernetes port-forward locally on EC2 instance

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-ec2, putty, portforwarding

I am running a minikube Kubernetes cluster on an EC2 instance for testing purposes (I'm not using EKS). I installed the official Jenkins helm chart and the pods are all healthy. I am trying to be able to load Jenkins in my browser, such as at http://localhost:8080.

I sshed into my box via putty and ran the following to port forward:

```
 kubectl port-forward service/jenkins 8080:8080
```

When I open up EC2 connect and curl http://localhost:8080/login?from=%2F, I get back the HTML for the login page so its clearly working. However, I can't figure out how to get this url to work locally from my browser.

I thought this should work but its not. Do I really need to do https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/amazon-ec2-instance-port-forwarding-with-aws-systems-manager/ instead?